# Font weight incorrect on mobile/tablet device

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, tablet

I've implemented the following font on [my website](https://www.slagerijrudi.be/broodjes/).

```
/* Vivaldi Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'vivaldi';
    src: url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('assets/fonts/vivaldi/vivaldi.svg#vivaldi') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I have applied these to my headers as follows:

```
/* Headers in Vivaldi */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: vivaldi;
}

/* Page titles in Vivaldi */
.page-title h1, #page .page-title .entry-title, .page-title h1 > span {
    font-family: vivaldi !important;
}
```

But I'm having some issues with the display of the font on mobile/tablet. When checking the preview via Google Developer tools, I see the following header styles: [Screenshot from Google Dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mlSK.png). However, when actually checking the font on my iPhone 5, I see the following display: [Screenshot from iPhone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc5U3.png).

The font seems even worse on iPad. There, it seems like the font is displayed double printed. Here you can see some screenshots from iPad: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqQm3.jpg) & [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fpSX.jpg)

You can see the font weight seems less on the actual mobile device. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I tried to adapt the font weights for my mobile/tablet device, but this doesn't seem to work at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that "double" visualization of the fonts might depend on the attempt of IOS Browser to render the font itself as "bold" (that's indeed the way a lot of mobile browser render h1-h6 by default).

You should reset the font weight explicitily and check if it helps:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: vivaldi;
    font-weight: normal!important;
}
```

Comment: Adding ``!important` is not necessary and removes the possibility of adding bold back in later.

Comment: I suggested that just as attempt, indeed, i have no idea of the structure of the whole project code...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was related to my theme settings. My typography settings were set on a font having font weight 800. However, I had overwritten the font-family in my custom CSS. What was not overwritten yet, were the font weights from the theme settings. As a consequence, the CSS tries to reproduce this font weight, although my font doesn’t have the ability to render this font weight. This gave the very strange font lay-out. So the solution of @holden would have worked, but I deleted the font weight from my theme settings instead.

However, I don’t understand why the font seemed correctly rendered on desktop, but not on mobile/desktop... maybe another format was selected depending on the browser (svg versus woff versus eot?).